# jamesdbloom/mockserver with maven

Tags: java, android, maven

I can't download the jars via maven. I get this error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1: Could not find artifact org.mock-server:mockserver:jar:3.6.2 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1: Could not find artifact org.mock-server:mockserver:jar:3.6.2 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockserver</artifactId>
         <version>3.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

After `maven clean install` the local repository contains this:

```
dasralph@ralphs-MacBook ~/.m2/repository/org/mock-server/mockserver/3.6.2 $ ls
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  6 dasralph  staff   204B 31 Okt 11:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 dasralph  staff   102B 31 Okt 11:23 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 dasralph  staff   156B 31 Okt 11:23 _maven.repositories
-rw-r--r--  1 dasralph  staff   235B 31 Okt 11:23 mockserver-3.6.2.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 dasralph  staff    25K 31 Okt 11:23 mockserver-3.6.2.pom
-rw-r--r--  1 dasralph  staff    40B 31 Okt 11:23 mockserver-3.6.2.pom.sha1
```

What's going wrong?

Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mockserver artifact is just the parent pom (with pom packaging) of several mockserver modules like mockserver-netty. Try to specify a module artifact from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mock-server). For example, to use MockServer with Netty add the following:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
     <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```